# What's name of plastic head connector of Daewoo AGC0070RF?

Tags: nissan, audio

What's name of plastic head connector for Daewoo AGC0070RF?

24 pin connector (pins in single line, every pin vertically flat)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it to be a male ribbon cable connector. Probably to interface a CD player unit
in a automotive audio system.